# Polylang plugin, How to setting some language go to other website

Tags: wordpress, polylang

I have WordPress website and use Polylang plugin for multilanguage.
I have 3 languages(English, Thai, Chinese).
I want to set only 1 language to go to another website.

Example

my WordPress URL is domain/wordpress/

I tried setting in URL modifications but it is not working

Dashboard> Languages > Settings and select option "The language is set from different domains".

EN - domain

TH - domain/wordpress/

ZH - domain/wordpress/zh/home_zh/